# Paypal recurring subscriptions question

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions

When someone starts a recurring subscription, i pass on the `custom` variable which contains the User ID of the user on my system. After the payment I receive two IPNs, subscr_signup and subscr_payment. Both have the custom variable in them which lets me identify the user.

However, for future recurring payments, will the IPN continue to pass on the custom variable? Should I rely on the subscr_id instead of custom?

Thanks.

Comment: great question, wondering it myself!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer from [this page](http://www.pdncommunity.com/pdn/board/message?board.id=ipn&thread.id=7215). Yes, the custom variable will always be passed as-is in every consecutive IPN post.

Quote:

> Custom is passed back through both the signup and payment IPN posts and is passed back through the consecutive IPN posts.  There is not a variable that is passed back in the first payment IPN that is not reproduced in the consecutive ones.  The only distinguishable factor would be the sign-up or if there was a different price for the first period of payment.

Comment: "this page" is gone... wish you had mentioned the name of the question on the forums... oh well.

Comment: @ftrotter sorry! But the info remains correct I think! Good thing I quoted the relevant part!