# Is the "custom" variable sent every reoccurring payment? If not, is that possible?

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I have a IPN response script that uses the "custom" variable that was posted in the initial form request , which contains the username of the payee. The first payment will send the  variable no problem but will it continue to send the same variable each month the payment is made? If not, is there a variable I can use that will keep it stored and sent each month?

The basic idea of what I'm trying to accomplish: http://pastebin.com/552u7QTG

Comment: can you show us your code ?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/552u7QTG

Basically, just wondering if I can rely on that $_POST["custom"] to posted with the same username every month of a reoccurring subscription?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I found the answer from this page. Yes, the custom variable will
>   always be passed as-is in every consecutive IPN post.
>
> Quote:
>
> Custom is passed back through both the signup and payment IPN posts
>   and is passed back through the consecutive IPN posts. There is not a
>   variable that is passed back in the first payment IPN that is not
>   reproduced in the consecutive ones. The only distinguishable factor
>   would be the sign-up or if there was a different price for the first
>   period of payment.

[Paypal recurring subscriptions question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/486626/paypal-recurring-subscriptions-question)

Found it! Yes it does!